# Implementing Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) with PyMC

Tags: pymc, lda

PyMC comes with numerous examples but LDA, which is a relatively simple graphical model, is not one of them. There are questions on numerous sites about this but never any references to implementations. I've considered how it might be implemented but it's not clear how PyMC would be used to establish the topic-word dependencies within each document.

Can LDA be implemented relatively easily with PyMC?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement and explore the solution provided in the link by Tom Minka and found that it gives some nice results. However, I am yet to find with 100% confidence that this implementation is the correct LDA implementation.

The ipython notebook can be viewed at: https://github.com/napsternxg/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/PyMC_LDA.ipynb